# How to get the store id from the any category id

Tags: magento-1.9, category, stores, store-id

So I have the category id and I would really like simply the store id. Ideally I do not want to simply load the store completely as I only need the id.

Here my meaning of category id is: One Root Category is assigned to store. My Structure of categories are:

- Root Category

  - Main Category

    - Cat1

      - Cat11

Like this type of structure lots of categories , child categories , their child categories and so on. When i pass id of any category then i want store id in which they are present. Either i pass category or child or child of any child category id.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(2);
print_r($category->getStore()->getId());
```

Comment: I have multistore, how can i display selected store products using store id, my code -> justpaste.it/6fi1f

Comment: Try : $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

OR
<?php
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(); 
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
?>